# Create a form element in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, appendchild, createelement

I can not create a form element in the body tag and display it directly in Javascript.

Here is my code :

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var elemForm = document.createElement('form');
});
```

I've tried things with appendChild but i didn't succeed.

(I'm french)

Answer (score 2):

`elemBody`, as specified above, contains an array, which in turn contains one element, the single `body` element of your html document. Calling `elemBody.appendChild` will result in an error, because you're trying to add `elemForm` to an array (using a method not defined for arrays), not a DOM element. If you update your code as below, you might have better success:

```
var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var elemForm = document.createElement('form');
elemBody.appendChild(elemForm);
```

Of course, you won't be able to detect the presence of the new form *visually* without styling it or adding some actual content to the form.

**UPDATE**

This is easier here than in the comments. If you want to be able to see what you've added visually, try this:

```
var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var elemForm = document.createElement('form');
elemForm.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'));
elemBody.appendChild(elemForm);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a complete test file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit() {
  var elemBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var elemForm = document.createElement('form');
  elemForm.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'));
  elemBody.appendChild(elemForm);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="doit()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i style form element by using a css file, it doesn't work, why ?

Comment: well, let's work on your current problem here. why don't you create a `textarea` and append that to `elemForm` so you can prove that the form is showing up. If you want help styling a form after that, it would be more appropriate to create a separate question.

Comment: I've created a `select` tag and it does'nt appear even in the source code by using `createElement` and `appendChild`

Comment: 1. If you add a select with no `option` tags for children, it won't display. 2. When you add elements with JavaScript, you won't see them when you view source.

Comment: So, how will i see them ?

Comment: Have a look at the update

Comment: I've tried your code : no results. Did you test it ?

Comment: Yes. Did you place my code in your load event listener, or did you just stick it in `script` tags, never to execute? See my latest update for my complete test.

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? In IE9, I get an error when trying to use `addEventListener`--that could be the source of your problem, as well.

Comment: It's a duty, i'm forced to use `addEventListener` so ?

Comment: If you're forced to use `addEventListener` in a browser that doesn't support it, then you can't make this work. Why are you forced to use it?

Comment: I've tried with Chrome et Firefox. I'm forced to use it because it's written in the duty.